# What type of chart is this? (bubble charts with links)

Tags: data-visualization

Does anybody know what type of chart that is? (some sort of bubble chart but with links between bubbles)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PageRanks-Example.svg
[image]

Comment: Typically 'bubble graph' is on an x-y coordinate system with no connections between bubbles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'd just call it a directed graph (digraph) where the nodes have values (fields, attributes) which are expressed as visual attributes (size, color, label). I'm using "graph" in the mathematical sense and not as a synonym for "chart".

Such graphs can be drawn with [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org), and other software. (Though I'm not sure how to achieve the gaudy 3D effect.)

[Edited once for each comment so far: Greg Snow, whuber, and Henry.]

Comment: Since the connections have a direction (arrows) it could be called a directed graph.

Comment: @GregSnow: Excellent point. I'll edit to add that.

Comment: What distinction are you making between "directed graph" and "directed network graph"?

Comment: The nodes have values (which determine the size and apparently the colours)

Comment: @whuber: Good point. I've deleted the word "network", but added a sentence to explain that the usage of "graph" (which in popular usage can be synonymous with "chart").

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that digraph is (at least sometimes) a synonym  or abbreviation for "directed graph" too....